# How many possible placements are there for a Battleship puzzle?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am studying the NP-Completeness of the battleship puzzle; the pencil and paper game found in newspapers and not the more popular 2-player version. I understand why the puzzle is NP-Complete because the number of possible placements on the grid for where all the ships may be is likely greater than a polynomial function. However, I cannot figure out how I would actually show this because placing various sized ships greatly complicates the basic strategy for calculating the permutations. 
$$n\sum_{i=0}^n$$ of $n \choose i$, is what I figured would probably be the number of combinations for an $n$ x $n$ grid. How would I show that the function for possible battleship puzzle solutions is greater than polynomial?

Comment: NP-completeness is not contingent on the size of a problem.

Comment: How long are the ships and how many of those we have? I think you can model a Matching with them and some nice permanent thing should come up.

Comment: In my example I am using only 4 ships of sizes { 2, 3, 3, 4}. This is probably a very small example, but showing a visual for the bin-packing reduction was difficult for a PowerPoint slide for more than 4 or 5 ships.

Comment: @Pockets Yes, I would like to be able to figure out a simple function that would give a fairly accurate estimate based upon the size of the grid so that it could be adapted to larger grid sizes.

Comment: To prove a given problem is in NPC, you reduce it to an NPC instance. In other words, you need a well-defined mapping from every instance of your problem to instances of problems known to be NPC.

Comment: @Pockets, I used an academic paper to learn the basics of reducing bin-packing to the battleships problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding involved in this question, and it should be closed as such.

If you are having trouble understanding NP-completeness, I'll point you to [Carl Kingford's slide deck](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/npcomplete.pdf) on the topic, which breaks down the mechanisms of the topic well.

From a more general perspective, I will say this: first, the *size* of a problem has nothing to do with whether or not it is NPC (moreover, how do you even define the "size" of a problem? the input size, the set of possible solutions, etc.?). It's an ill-defined term and even if you have exponentially many possible solutions, there are known problems that satisfy such criteria with polynomial-time solutions, such as the lexicographical distance between two arbitrary strings.

The *purpose* of proving a problem to be NP-complete is that by demonstrating it to be such, then providing a polynomial-time algorithm for any NPC problem is equivalent to providing a polynomial-time algorithm for *every* NPC problem.